# Looking for a short story about a parallel world with apparently ordinary humans but savage and carnivorous

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

I read this a long time ago, and thought it was Larry Niven but maybe not.

A bunch of scientists build a gate to a parallel world and initially observe the inhabitants on the other side. They seem to be a typical Midwest rural family (I think that's the right description but I am a Brit ;-))

A couple of them step through and a little girl smiles at them, then her grin gets wider revealing sharp predator's teeth and she instantly attacks.

The family rips the travellers apart and throws their bones back through the gate.

The head of the household then retrieves a book and reads from it in the manner of a preacher, causing the gate to slam shut and thereby demonstrating both knowledge of gates and some form of magic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When exactly did you read this? A long time ago can be any number of years :)

Comment: Probably over 40 years. I'm 63 and this would, I think, be in my teens or early twenties.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate. That does not mean that it is a bad question, merely one that we've had - and which has been answered - before. You will still receive points for upvotes and people can still leave comments.

Comment: Wow, this has to be trending as one of the most asked about stories. And it was memorable for sure.

Answer (score 8):

You're probably remembering [Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_(short_story))
written by Bob Leman.

The story is pretty much as you state, the protagonist finds a window/portal that shows what appears to be an idyllic family farm from Victorian times.  He falls in love with a girl on the farm and eventually makes his way through to meet her... and is promptly eaten.

The story was dramatised in the 1990's as an episode of the anthology show Night Visions.

Have found the Night Visions dramatisation on Youtube

Comment: No it's not that one though I'll definitely read it. This is a bunch of scientists and a sort of first-contact situation.

Comment: @SimonLyon: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251452/short-story-where-a-device-tosses-dry-ice-into-another-dimension?noredirect=1&lq=1 explains more of the story, including the reading from the book to close the portal.

Comment: @SimonLyon I think you'll find this is actually the answer, down to throwing the bones of the researcher back.  Ignoring the basically useless link above, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/220018/101407) actually provides useful details, including a [link to the original published version of the story](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v058n05_1980-05#page/n5/mode/1up).

Comment: Yeah, that's the one! Many thanks!

Comment: @SimonLyon You're welcome!  Please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark in the upper left beneath the voting arrows.